how to solve the Navagation Selected status while switch Fragment?
first step: switch home_fragment to dashboard_fragment by  navagation controller
second step : switch dashboard_fragment to scan_fragment as below
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment);
                navController.navigate(R.id.dashToScan);
            }

third step: switch scan_fragment to notification_fragment
fourth step: switch notification_fragment to dashboard_fragment by  navagation controller
after fourth step, the scan_fragment is presented but the navagation is still in Notification
show as below

Can anyone please give me some advice on how to fix this problem?
i try as below
in onDestinationChanged
navView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_dashboard);
navView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navigation_dashboard).setChecked(true);


Try clearing focus
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    navController.navigate(R.id.dashToScan);
    v.clearFocus();
}


while switch notification_fragment to dashboard_fragment, the navigation is not correct selected

the correct select item is Dashboard, not Notification

@HunterChen , instead of clearing focus, try requesting focus on the clicked item
